# register bit access using structure union combinations

Tags: microcontroller, arm

I have a structure something like this in device header file:

```
 typedef struct {     
  union {
__IOM uint32_t DR;                          
    struct {
      __IOM uint32_t D0      : 1;     
      __IOM uint32_t D1      : 1;         
      __IOM uint32_t D2      : 1;           
      __IOM uint32_t D3      : 1;           
    } DR_b;
  } ;
  } GPIO_PRT4_Type; 

#define GPIO_PRT4                   ((GPIO_PRT4_Type*)         GPIO_PRT4_BASE)
```

To change bit D0 of DR register, I am using below line in application code

```
GPIO_PRT4->DR_b.D0 = 1;
```

On using the above line, MCU goes into hard fault handler.

Assembler code for above line is:

```
0x01a0  ldr r3, [pc, #16]   ; (0x1b4 <main+52>)
0x01a2  ldrb    r2, [r3, #0]
0x01a4  movs    r1, #1
0x01a6  orrs    r2, r1
0x01a8  strb    r2, [r3, #0]

0x01aa  b.n 0x196 <main+22>
```

Any idea, what is wrong here??

MCU: ARM Cortex CM0plus

Comment: You could try changing the pointer to point to general purpose ram, and then check if the operation is modifying the ram in the way that you expect? Also, can you get more information from the hardfault handler about the exact cause of the fault?

Comment: I checked stack window and disassembly window. I am sure as soon as I uses the line "GPIO_PRT4->DR_b.D0 = 1;" , it causes hardfault. However on using "GPIO_PRT4->DR = 0x08;", everything works fine

Comment: I am not sure, works for me https://ideone.com/YIBM9s

Comment: Is GPIO_PRT4_BASE correct?

Comment: Setting `D0 = 1` and `DR = 0x08` aren't the same - what if you set `D3 = 1`?

Comment: I think the issue might be due to packing, I have always used the packed attribute when I have made these types of things. Find out how you can pack the structure in your compiler and apply that attribute?

Comment: @Wayne: yes GPIO_PRT4_BASE is correct. I gave DR=0x08 just as an eample

Comment: @Jeroen: This is how assembly looks like on using 'GPIO_PRT4->DR_b.D0 = 1;'   '0x01a0 ldr r3, [pc, #16] ; (0x1b4 <main+52>)
0x01a2 ldrb r2, [r3, #0]
0x01a4 movs r1, #1
0x01a6 orrs r2, r1
0x01a8 strb r2, [r3, #0]
0x01aa b.n 0x196 <main+22>'

Comment: Please add the assembler in the question.

Comment: @Jeroen3, added assembler code

Comment: The last assembler instructions LDRB and STRB. Is the region you are using accessing byte-accessible? Not all periopherals are.

Comment: @WayneUroda, I tried adding packed attribute, but still problem is same 'typedef __PACKED_STRUCT { '

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen, it should be byte accessible, but i don't know, Any idea how to check it?

Comment: Give us the correct make and model. GPIO access is *not* part of the Cortex-M0 core, at it may actually need 32-bit access.

Comment: If you haven't read that it is byte accessible, you should not assume that it is. Read the chip manual/datahseet (not the Cortex documentation), this is chip-specific.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen, yeah it seems chip is not supporting byte wise access. If I am adding reserved bits into the structure to make it 32 bits and then access it, everything works fine without causing any hardfault handler.

Comment: Is there any way to force compiler to always access 32 bit instead of byte access? I am using GCC ARM Compiler. There should be some way to force compiler.